# Python function utilizes variables passed to it as well as NOT passed to it. What is the difference?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

The below code works to my surprise. When would it be necessary to pass values as arguments then?

```
x=3
y=4
def adder():
    return x + y
```

Comment: x & y are global variables. See https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_global_variables.asp

Comment: Those are *global variables* - note that you can only read from them, writing to a global variable requires an explicit `global` declaration inside the function.  The limitation is that your function can only add those two particular variables; as parameters, you could call the function to add any two variables you want.

Comment: What do you mean it works? Have you posted the full code? It doesn't work for me...

Comment: I was trying it in a script , not in the shell, my bad

Comment: works in a script, too. just add `print(adder())` at the bottom. :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code worked is because both `x` and `y` already existed as global variables. If you tried the same thing, just with `a` and `b` in your function, nothing would happen.

Asides from that, the whole point of having a function is that you could supply it with *any* numbers, and it would still work. Your code could be replaced with  `print (7)` and it would do the same thing, whereas if you set it up with parameters it could add any 2 numbers

Answer (score 0):

Variables outside the scope of a function are called *global*; using them is widely considered bad practice. They're dangerous precisely because the fact that a function is using them is not visible in the function call.

You should only use them if you actually need shared state across multiple functions that would be cumbersome to pass around - and even then, you probably want to make an object to hold that state and call methods on the object instead of using global variables and functions.

Comment: But I also see that editing parameters passed into the function also affects the global variable, such as a list.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: Say a list is mylist = [1,2,3]. You make a function that has mylist passed to it, appends 4. After you run the function, the original mylist now has 4. It seems the parameter you passed to it was a pointer to the global value, not a copy of it. 

Thus, it seems whether you pass a parameter or not, it's operating on global values.

Comment: Update: I found my answer...functions will by default change global values of parameters passed to it if they are mutable.

Comment: That's an artifact of pass-by-reference. If you pass a list or a dict to a function, what that function actually gets is a reference, through which it can modify the referenced object. Regardless of whether the object passed is global or a local in the caller's scope, or even a literal, though modifying a literal list has no visible effect in the calling context.